# can i secure sql server agent job with password

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, password

I want to secure SQL Server Agent jobs with password or any other method is it possible?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such feature to safegurad job with password. You have to make sure proper rights given to account which are using the job so that they can run only what is required

Answer (score 2):

One alternative method which might help you out is to save your stored procedures and UDFs that the job may use (if any) WITH ENCRYPTION.

However, given the nature of your question, I wonder whether you really need to start a bottom-up review of your database systems security first, liaising with business owners regarding what permissions currently exist, and what the desired position should look like.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the Roles in the msdb and using the roles for the SQL Server Agent.

Detailed description can be found in the following article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190926.aspx